# Unity3d Network, port is not opened

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

I try to create a simple network example over the internet. This is the code:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (Network.isServer)
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 30), "Server is started");
    }
    else
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 30), "Create Server"))
        {
            Network.InitializeServer(10, 25000, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I turn off the firewall and antivirus programs. I forward the port 25000 into my local IP address.

Then I run the program and click on "Create Server" button to make it running and go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to check whether my port is opened. The result is always "closed". What did I do wrong?

NOTE:

- I tested the port with other application to make sure that it is not blocked by ISP.
- This is what I got by using netstat http://screencast.com/t/qzArfnxxH

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I checked my ISP, they blocked UDP packages.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the described problem was caused by a non-programming issue, as stated by the OP. 